# How do you remove/reset javascript date sliders that were created programmatically?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Good day! Hoping someone can help me out with the issue I'm seeing.

I'm creating a bunch of javascript date sliders like this:

```
// Create the slider for this product.
$("#Product" + index).dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: { min: new Date(2010, 10, 1), max: new Date(2018, 10, 1, 23, 59, 59) }, // yyyy-m-d HH:MM:SS
    defaultValues: { min: new Date(StartDate[0], StartDate[1] - 1, StartDate[2]), max: new Date(EndDate[0], EndDate[1] - 1, EndDate[2]) }, // yyyy-mm-dd, slider starts month from 0, hence the "-1".
    allowResize: false
}).bind("valuesChanged", myEventHandler);
```

They are "attached" to`<div />` elements that looks like this:

```
<div style="top: 6em; position: absolute; margin-left: 175px">
    <div id="Product1" style="width: 950px; margin-left: 60px">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a bunch of these `<div />` elements and the javascript loops through them all and creates a slider for each one.

Here' the problem: When I call it the first time, it works great. If I call the javascript routine again (after updating the number of things I want to display - either add/remove) things look really messed up. The formatting is way off: The sliders are pushed way out of the `<div />` elements, the boxes with the dates that are attached to the sliders aren't in the correct location, etc.

It's like I need to remove all the sliders and then re-add them - a sort of "reset" for everything created by the first call that generated the sliders. I haven't the slightest idea how to do this, or if this is even the fix for the problem.

Any ideas?

Help! :)

Comment: I suggest you make your title a little more specific. There is no generic way to reset things like monads.

Comment: Put together a sample of what you are talking about in a jsfiddle

Comment: That's a jquery plugin you're using. Do you know the URL for its documentation page?

Comment: Here's the plugin URL that talks about the "destroy" option: http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#bindingEvents I'm trying to get this to work right now - no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this: (not tested)

In the loop before creating the dateRangeSlider:

```
$("#Product"+index).unbind();
$("#Product"+index).html("");
```

You might need to reset the inline styles from your html - not sure about that one - give it a try.

Comment: The `html("")` do unbind anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery  has a method called [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) that allows you to remove DOM elements.  Blend that in with a setTimeOut() function, based on certain conditions, and you should be able to come a little closer to what you want to achieve.